# DateRangePicker in ASP.NET with MasterPage not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, daterangepicker

**My code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="lb.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/bootstrap.Master" Inherits="rt.lb" %>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />

        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                    opens: 'right'
                }, function (start, end, label) {
                    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

This code refers to [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config) site. I have a simple ASP.NET page asking user to select series of dates. Unfortunately, after running this code nothing happens. Is this something to do with Bootstrap?

I am beginner in jQuery but able to understand coding in ASP.NET.

Comment: Check browser developer tools (F12) for any console errors? I suspect that you have multiple references of jquery one included on master page and other on the content page

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohsin Mehmood. F12 did the trick.

Comment: Were there any errors in console?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mohsin Mehmood. F12 did the trick. There were two errors - Error 1 **jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function** and Error 2 (from MasterPage) - **GET http://localhost/rttest/~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)**. I removed the error for bootstrap.min.js and it worked. I still do not know the reason. For removing bootstrap error on Masterpage I got help from - [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951517/jquery-deferred-exception-datepicker-is-not-a-function)